# Reterive the Status of the Subscriber from subscriber.aspx

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am planning to have a link, Change Communication Preferences on my landing page. By Clicking on this link I need to retrieve the Status of the Subscriber, so that I can send them to Unsubscribe Page or Re-Subscribe Page based on what their Status is in ET.

I am able to Subscribe, Re-Subscribe and Unsubscribe using the below code. I am just submitting my email address to subscribe.aspx and it is doing everything(Below is the code and link where I got that code sample from). I am hoping that this file can return me the Status of the subscriber as well.

Please let me know if that is possible. Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Shamita
Web Developer
BrightWave Marketing

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/#Sample_Code_For_Subscribing_to_or%20Unsubscribing_From_a_Single_List

Email:
        
        
    
        
            
            Subscribe
            
        
            
            Unsubscribe